# Programmatically update Default Bucket Query in a Saved Search

Tags: sitecore-client, buckets

I need to programmatically update the Default Bucket Query in a Saved Search in Sitecore. I am fairly new to this area, how do I get this done?

Comment: What do you mean grammatically? Do you mean you need SiteCore to be spelled correctly Sitecore :D

Comment: Sorry I meant programatically :).  I have access to the SavedSearch item in SiteCore however I dont know how to access the "Default Bucket Query" field and perform the udpate.

Comment: Do you know item id? If you do, have you tried getting item by id from the database and changing field's value? Eg.: http://learnsitecore.cmsuniverse.net/Developers/Articles/2009/06/ProgramaticallyItems2.aspx

Comment: When do you need to change this value? Just as a one off? or an event such as when the search page is loaded in the CMS?

Comment: I actually need to change it on an item:updated even.  The user basically creates an item off a branch template and on the creation process I need to point this saved search into the proper location.

Answer (score 2):

### Updating the field

The field you need is ID `Sitecore.Buckets.Util.Constants.DefaultQuery` and then if you have your query already you can just update it.

```
BucketItem.Editing.BeginEdit();
BucketItem.Fields[Sitecore.Buckets.Util.Constants.DefaultQuery].Value = ['The query you want in there']
BucketItem.Editing.AcceptChanges();
```

The query looks like this `+location:021e2ec55a614a3d8b2f5575e709c632;template:{03360FC1-B4C0-4770-9E1D-79E8317B74DD}`. So you can update it to whatever you want.

### Doing it on an item created from a branch template

As far as your branch update goes, I would do that work in a AddFromTemplate pipeline. This gives you the ability to focus on branches and not every single time an item is updated.

```
public class AddFromBranchPreset : AddFromTemplateProcessor
{
    public override void Process(AddFromTemplateArgs args)
    {
        Assert.ArgumentNotNull(args, nameof(args));

        if (args.Destination.Database.Name != "master") return;

        var templateItem = args.Destination.Database.GetItem(args.TemplateId);

        Assert.IsNotNull(templateItem, "Template did not exist!");

        // if this isn't a branch template, we can use the stock behavior
        if (templateItem.TemplateID != TemplateIDs.BranchTemplate) return;

        [DO YOUR BRANCH WORK HERE]

    }
}
```

The config is like this

```
<!-- Add this to App_Config/Include to enable branch presets -->
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
    <sitecore>
        <pipelines>
            <group name="itemProvider" groupName="itemProvider">
                <pipelines>
                    <addFromTemplate>
                        <processor type="YourApp.BranchPresets.AddFromBranchPreset, YourApp.BranchPresets" />
                    </addFromTemplate>
                </pipelines>
            </group>
        </pipelines>
    </sitecore>
</configuration>
```